# Can i enable asking for confirmation when executing a pasted command in bash?

Tags: bash, clipboard

I heard zsh has a feature where it asks for confirmation executing pasted commands, is there something I can put in my .bashrc to make bash ask before executing commands that were pasted in the terminal?

Comment: What version of `bash`? Bracketed paste only got added in readline 7/bash 4.4, from some delving

Comment: I'm currently on 4.3.43, but could you explain how to enable it on 4.4?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=Bracketed+paste+%5Bbash%5D&tab=votes